# Xamarin.Forms - Label FontSize OnPlatform - XAML error

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have this code:

```
  <Label x:Name="questionGroupHintInfoLabel" FontAttributes="Bold"  Text="Folgende Hinweismeldung wurde für die aktuelle Fragengruppe hinterlegt:">
      <Label.FontSize>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="NamedSize"
                    iOS="Small"
                    Android="Small" />
      </Label.FontSize>
    </Label>
```

...and get this error:

```
No property, bindable property, or event found for FontSize
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually when we set `FontSize="value"`, [`FontSizeConverter`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/FontSizeConverter.cs) does the conversion to [expected type](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Label.cs#L129) (which is `double`) to set the value.

But it looks like this converter is not used when we use `OnPlatform`. So we have two options:

1. Use `OnPlatform` with `x:Double` as type argument.

   ```
   <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
       iOS="20"
       Android="25" />
   ```
2. Or, trick the XAML processor to do the conversion for us - we can do that by using the `StaticResource` markup extension. **Note:** *This only works if XAMLC is not applied.*

   ```
   <!-- App.Resources or ContentPage.Resources -->
   <ResourceDictionary>
       <OnPlatform x:Key="FontNamedSize" x:TypeArguments="x:String"
           iOS="Small"
           Android="Large" />
   </ResourceDictionary>

   <!-- now you can use static-resource extension to use above defined value -->
   <Label x:Name="questionGroupHintInfoLabel" 
          FontAttributes="Bold"  
          Text="Folgende Hinweismeldung wurde für die aktuelle Fragengruppe hinterlegt:" 
          FontSize="{StaticResource FontNamedSize}" />
   ```
3. **Recommended** Extend `Label` with `NamedSize` bindable property and convert to `FontSize` (basically what the `FontSizeConverter` does).

   ```
   public class ExLabel : Label
   {
       public static readonly BindableProperty FontNamedSizeProperty =
           BindableProperty.Create(
               "FontNamedSize", typeof(NamedSize), typeof(ExLabel),
               defaultValue: default(NamedSize), propertyChanged: OnFontNamedSizeChanged);

       public NamedSize FontNamedSize
       {
           get { return (NamedSize)GetValue(FontNamedSizeProperty); }
           set { SetValue(FontNamedSizeProperty, value); }
       }

       private static void OnFontNamedSizeChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
       {
           ((ExLabel)bindable).OnFontNamedSizeChangedImpl((NamedSize)oldValue, (NamedSize)newValue);
       }

       protected virtual void OnFontNamedSizeChangedImpl(NamedSize oldValue, NamedSize newValue)
       {
           FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(FontNamedSize, typeof(Label));
       }
   }

   <!-- Usage -->
   <local:ExLabel HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="This is a custom label">
       <local:ExLabel.FontNamedSize>
           <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="NamedSize"
               iOS="Large"
               Android="Medium" />
       </local:ExLabel.FontNamedSize>
   </local:ExLabel>
   ```

***EDIT 1:*** Option 2 only works if XAMLC is not applied.

***EDIT 2:*** Add option 3.

**Note:** There is a [bug fix available in pre-release versions](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=54416) that can also be considered as an alternative fix. But I haven't been able to confirm if it is fixed in the latest release.

Comment: Thanks but the second approach gives me this error at runtime:  System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: @OPunktSchmidt : Updated answer with another option. Hope it helps!

Comment: they labeled this issue as resolved but it is still an issue. there is a new issue on github now https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2077

Answer (score 5):

old thread, but i was close to implement item 3 from answer above, when i find this syntax

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="ListButtonStyle">
       <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{OnIdiom Phone={OnPlatform Android=Header, iOS=Micro} , Tablet=Large, Desktop=Default}" />
</Style>
```

checked it with phones with ios and android and it is working nicely .
decided to leave it here.
xamarin.forms 4.8.0.1687

Comment: This is much better than the 3 options Sharada put and it worked on my 5.0 Forms app.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the new XAML for OnPlatform:

```
<!--Old XAML On Platform-->
<StackLayout>
  <StackLayout.Padding>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" 
                Android="0, 0, 0, 0" 
                WinPhone="0, 0, 0, 0" 
                iOS="0, 20, 0, 0"/>
  </StackLayout.Padding>
</StackLayout>

<!--New XAML On Platform-->
<StackLayout>
  <StackLayout.Padding>
   <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
     <On Platform="Android" Value="0, 0, 0, 0"/>
     <On Platform="WinPhone" Value="0, 0, 0, 0"/>
     <On Platform="iOS" Value="0, 20, 0, 0"/>
    </OnPlatform>
  </StackLayout.Padding>
</StackLayout>

<!--Better new XAML On Platform-->
<StackLayout>
  <StackLayout.Padding>
   <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
     <On Platform="Android, WinPhone">0</On>
     <On Platform="iOS">0,20,0,0</On>
    </OnPlatform>
  </StackLayout.Padding>
</StackLayout>
```