# change font family for picker dialog box in ios using xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using xamarin forms for my app develepment. I need to change font family for the dialog box of picker on iOS. For example, in  attched image, The "Baboon,Capuchin Monkey,Blue Monkey" texts need to change custom font.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Google is your friend. [Xamarin Forms - Fonts - Set font properties per platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts#set-font-properties-per-platform).

Comment: The answers to this related question show how to set font size per platform: [Xamarin.Forms - Label FontSize OnPlatform - XAML error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46274052/xamarin-forms-label-fontsize-onplatform-xaml-error)